# React Native road map

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin

```
[Maybe this is a off-topic question]
```

I started learning React Native from couple of months
But I don't know if i am on the right path or not

Some of my queries are

1. Is Data Structure must (Pro level)?
2. Must know Native Development (Kotlin)?
3. Are plenty of jobs available for it?
4. Any other suggestions do you have for me please mention

Sorry for asking a silly off-topic question here.

Answer (score 1):

React native ecosystem is wide as intersect both native mobile and web development.

1. Solidify your modern JavaScript skills (ES6+)
2. Understand how React works from a web perspective - Strongly   recommended.
3. Familiarize with basic React Native concepts - Use Expo snack for  development  and testing - http://snack.expo.io/
4. When you 're confident with React Native, Try to setup local development with expo.io . At this stage, you don't have to spend week setup React Native CLI tooling ( Xcode or Android Studio and their dependencies.
5. Building real life apps - Either your local town weather app or food delivery app.
6. While building real apps. You will face with many challenges and in some case solutions will require learn in and out of native development for specific platforms  (iOS and Android)
7. Keep building and learning and ask help when you stuck. People here are mostly willing to help.
8. Finally, help others, fellow community members

Comment: Thanks. but is DS Algo must for becoming a RN dev? @BYIRINGIRO Emmanuel

Comment: Yes. It must for become software engineer in general